# C++ error: Member declaration not found

Tags: c++, declaration, member

I am a c++ newbie. Today, I have a problem:
in header file, I define a class:

```
template<class T> class Ptr_to_const {
private:
    Array_Data<T>* ap;
    unsigned sub;

public:
        ...

    Ptr_to_const<T> & operator=(const Ptr_to_const<T> & p);

};
```

and in source file, I program as:

```
template<class T> Ptr_to_const<T>& Ptr_to_const<T>::operator=(
        const Ptr_to_const<T> & p) {
         ...
    return *this;
}
```

when compiled, compiler always say: '**Member declaration not found**'.
**why?**

I use **eclipse CDT+Cygwin GCC**

thank you very much!

Comment: AFAIK you should not implement a template class in a source file. Set the definition of the function in the header.

Answer (score 6):

Template classes need to be both declared and defined in the header, or another file which is included by users. They can't be declared in a header and defined in a source file like usual.

The reasoning is that the template must be replaced with an actual type and the source for that generated and compiled when used, and the compiler certainly can't precompile templates for every possible type that may come along, so users need to be able to handle that (and so, need access to the code).

This does cause some issues when passing objects, if multiple libraries include the same templates, as they may be compiled against different versions of the header (see the One Definition Rule).

Answer (score 1):

"Member declaration not found" is an error produced by the Eclipse static analysis tool ([codan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis)) rather than compiler. If you get this error, but the compilation succeeds this is a false positive. Older versions of this tool are known to give some false positives, see for example [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357320). So I recommend updating Eclipse CDT to the most recent version. If this doesn't help, submit a bug report to Eclipse CDT.

However, if you get the errors from compiler too (these are indicated by C/C++ Problem in the Type column in the Problems view) then you have probably forgotten to include the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your source file at the end of header file 
or you define member function in header file when you define a template class